# Media Query Won't Override Original Style

Tags: html, css

I have a media query to change the look of a footer when the site goes mobile, but, for some reason, it doesn't seem to want to take the media query styles over the original base style. The specific CSS code is as follows

```
.footy {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url('../Images/LandingBottomRightCorner_FullSpan.png');
    background-position-x: right;
    min-height: 338px;
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.footytext {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 13px;
}

.footytextelement {
    color: white;
    font-size: 18pt;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.joinnow {
    border: 3px solid white;
    border-radius: 12px;
    font-style: italic;
    margin: 10px;
}


.footytext a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}


@media (max-width: 1279px) {

/*FOOTER APPEARANCE MOBILE*/
    .footy {
        background-repeat: repeat-x;
        background-image: url('../Images/MBLLandingFooterGradient_ForRepeat.png');
        height: 338px;
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

.footytext {
    position: center;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 13px;
}

.footytextelement {
    color: white;
    font-size: 16pt;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.joinnow {
    border: 3px solid white;
    border-radius: 12px;
    font-style: italic;
    margin: 10px;
}


.footytext a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}
}
```

The HTML being manipulated is:

```
<div class="footy">
    <div class="footytext">
        <div class="footytextelement">Make a plan.</div>
        <div class="footytextelement">Get medications.</div>
        <div class="footytextelement">Quit.</div>
        <a href="@Url.Action("Contact", "Home")"><div class="footytextelement joinnow">Join Now!</div></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
  .footy {
    background-color:red;
    background-position-x: right;
    min-height: 338px;
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.footytext {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 13px;
}

.footytextelement {
    color: white;
    font-size: 18pt;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.joinnow {
    border: 3px solid white;
    border-radius: 12px;
    font-style: italic;
    margin: 10px;
}


.footytext a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}


@media (max-width: 1279px) {

/*FOOTER APPEARANCE MOBILE*/
    .footy {
        background-color:green;
        background-position-x: right;
        background-position-y:bottom; 
        height: 338px;
        position: relative;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

.footytext {
    position: center;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 13px;
}

.footytextelement {
    color: white;
    font-size: 18pt;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.joinnow {
    border: 3px solid white;
    border-radius: 12px;
    font-style: italic;
    margin: 10px;
}


.footytext a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="footy">
    <div class="footytext">
        <div class="footytextelement">Make a plan.</div>
        <div class="footytextelement">Get medications.</div>
        <div class="footytextelement">Quit.</div>
       
    </div>
</div>
```

Your max-width in media query should be 768px as standard.
You have given 1279px which means no matter whether you are in mobile device or desktop, media query css will apply everywhere.

Comment: The size is that way on purpose due to what we are doing with the site. We have the media query taking over and showing a "mobile friendly" version of the footer/site when it gets below 1280px wide.

Comment: I have edited my answer here, as you can see if you go beyond 1279px, it changes the color green to red. Or else you try to add @media only screen and (max-width: 1279px), hope it will work for you.

Comment: This is working great now. However, I can't seem to get the text to center once it shrinks to the proper size. It just wants to stay the same.

Comment: Do you mean that the text should be in the center of the screen horizontally but not vertically?

Comment: @M.Straw Don't set footytext position to absolute make it relative or nothing, second set padding to 125px for top and bottom it would be in center.

Answer (score 0):

With that media's condition you are saying: apply these styles above 1279px.
Use min-width and max-width to get more control.

```
example:
@media (max-width: 719px) {...}
@media (max-width: 1023px) {...}
```

More information: [MDN LINK](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

Comment: That is the plan. The media query should go into effect when the site reaches less than 1280px wide. Right now, nothing from the media query wants to take effect when it hits 1279px and below.

Comment: I tried your code and it works, which browser are you using?